# Is there a formal command to get rsa key form sig file?

Tags: key, rsa, gnupg

```
gpg  gpgme-1.9.0.tar.bz2.sig
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: assuming signed data in 'gpgme-1.9.0.tar.bz2'
gpg: Signature made Tue 28 Mar 2017 10:36:41 PM HKT
gpg:                using RSA key D8692123C4065DEA5E0F3AB5249B39D24F25E3B6
gpg: Good signature from "Werner Koch (dist sig)" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: D869 2123 C406 5DEA 5E0F  3AB5 249B 39D2 4F25 E3B6
```

You can see that `using RSA key D8692123C4065DEA5E0F3AB5249B39D24F25E3B6`,got the RSA key `D8692123C4065DEA5E0F3AB5249B39D24F25E3B6`.
In the second line ,`gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...`  ,no command supplied ,`try to guess` means `gpg filename` is not a formal way to get RSA key in the filename,is there a formal command to get rsa key form sig file?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

Comment: It looks like most of your questions are off-topic and belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about). Please read the help sections for both sites to see what they're about.